# Glitches in VSCode Jupyter Notebook

Tags: visual-studio-code

[image]

My VSCode ipykernel was working just fine, until suddenly cell outputs started glitching by flashing grey as seen in the screenshot.

I tried restarting and updating the VSCode and the computer but it's still occurring.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's been a bug since 2022 and was documented heavily on github as well. So it is something about memory leak if I understand correctly.
You can try clearing the cache for the code, or specifically find the part of the code that might cause a huge deal of memory.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Creating a new notebook and copying the whole code worked for now, thanks